# Meteor Client Side Ajax POST not working on iOS 10 iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, ajax

1. I have a Meteor app (Angular JS running on iOS 10.0 iPhone 6 Plus)
2. This program perform ajax call to an ASP.NET WebAPI url from Meteor's Client controller and was not able to retrieve data; however if this same Meteor application run on my Apple Mac Pro laptop it works fine.
3. This application does not require the client codes to call a Meteor.Method on the Server Side codes
4. Is there some settings that I need to configure on my iPhone or within my Meteor application to allow the Ajax call to work properly?

Below is a ajax call:

```
url = 'http://pAPI.mydomain.Com:81/Api/GlgResults';

//alert('in ajax call now');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        Username: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        UserToken: '',
        State: state,
        Game: game,
        GameType: gameType,
        NumberType: numberType,
        StartDate: '2016-01-01', //startDate,
        EndDate: '2016-12-30', //endDate,
    },
    success: function (result) {
        //debugger
        //alert('in ajax call success');
        $scope.MMAjaxToMMResultsSuccess(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        //alert('in ajax call failed!');
        alert(xhr);
        alert('Request Status: ' + xhr.status + ' Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText + ' ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

After the Ajax call returned, the following message displayed:

```
Request Status: 0 Status Text: error
```

Basically, the response text is bank